# zabbix 5.X and MS teams integration

Tags: alert, microsoft-teams, zabbix, zabbix-api

I am trying to integrate alerting system from zabbix 5.2.6 to MS teams i am following below document but this doesn't seems to be working.

https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/msteams

can anyone please suggest a doc or any other lead would be appreciated.

Comment: please reach out to [product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels)

Comment: i didnt have any issue with this task in my environment with the official documentation, can you add more details and/or error messages?

Comment: @IronBishop Do we have place to check logs for this as I am doing all the configuration from console. Only place I am suspecting the error is where we add {ZABBIX.URL}  in Macros as I am having zabbix server behind Load balance and it doesn’t hit the zabbix UI directly ex http://lb-endpoint/zabbix.  Please suggest rest of the setting looks good to me.

zabbix version - 5.2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Doc](https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/msteams) works fine but need to keep three important configuration in mind that are not mentioned in the doc.

1. Administration -> General -> Macros -> add {$ZABBIX.URL} = http://DNSNAME/zabbix/ **You Must Get Zabbix UI**
2. **Enable** Configuration -> Actions -> Trigger actions -> Report problems to Zabbix administrators
3. You can send alerts via Admin user too.
   Administration -> Users -> Admin -> Media -> Type (MS Teams) -> Send to (MS team connector) -> update

**I tried on Zabbix 5.2.6** [Follow This Doc Link for more details](https://github.com/Shubhamjain6197/zabbix-Ms-teams-integration/blob/main/README.md)